# Code change to create TX for send between local addresses

Tags: transactions

Need to create a customised client to be able to create TXs on the blockchain when sending between local addresses. This can be done with Coin Control but needs to be done with a headless daemon.

I'm sure that someone will have enabled this on a Bitcoin client before and wondered if anyone knew a commit available for reference.

Comment: If you want the transaction to be recorded on the blockchain, how do you think that "sending to a local address" is any different than sending to any other address?